# Error when deploying python C packages on Google Cloud functions

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework, google-cloud-pubsub

I am deploying a Google Cloud function with python37 using `serverless-google-cloudfunctions`. This function uses the pubsub API to publish a message. However, I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython'
```

It seems to be because you can't pip install a C library with requirements.txt. How to I fix this?  My code is below.

```
from google.cloud import pubsub

publisher = pubsub.PublisherClient()
path = publisher.topic_path("my_proj", "my_topic")

publisher.publish(path, "test".encode("utf-8"))
```

My requirements.txt is the following. I have tried adding `grpcio==1.22.0` to no avail.

```
google-cloud-pubsub==0.45.0
```

My serverless.yml:

```
service: my-service

provider:
    name: google
    stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
    runtime: python37
    region: us-central1
    project: ${self:custom.env.PROJECT_NAME}
    credentials: ~/.gcloud/keyfile.json

plugins:
  - serverless-google-cloudfunctions
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
    pythonRequirements:
        fileName: private_requirements.txt
        pythonBin: python3
        noDeploy:
            - requirements.txt
    stage:
        ${self:provider.stage}
    env:
        ${file(./.env.${self:provider.stage})}

package:
    include:
        - requirements.txt
    exclude:
        - .git/**
        - .gitignore
        - env*
        - node_modules/**
        - package.json
        - private_requirements.txt
        - yarn.lock

functions:

    my-func:
        handler: func
        events:
            - http: path
```

Comment: What's your `requirements.txt` file content? What's your project structure? How to deploy your function?

Comment: Requirements.txt is listed above. Project structure is simply requirements.txt, serverless.yml, main.py, package.json in the root folder. I deploy with `serverless deploy`

Comment: Can you try to deploy with gcloud command ? The aim is to identify if the problem come from your code or from the deploy manager.

Comment: I just tried to deploy a function in the console with your code and it's working for me. I added both dependencies grpcio & pubsub, no problem.

Comment: I added the serverless.yml. The important part is that I am excluding the requirements.txt from the pre-deploy package install and then including the requirements file in the deployment package. This is because GCP installs requirements.txt when the package is uploaded and I have to install my private requirements with my git credentials before the package is uploaded.

Comment: is there a chance that you are trying to deploy this on firebase cloud functions instead gcp cloud functions?

Comment: @ChristianGonzalez Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this issue because I was using the serverless framework without docker. There is currently (as of Aug 29, 2019) [a bug](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/issues/272) in serverless-python-requirements that prevents dockerizing pip with private repositories.

My solution was to remove serverless and convert to the [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy). When you upload requirements.txt to GCloud it automatically installs the public ones but cannot install private repos because it doesn't have git credentials. To get around this, you must install those requirements locally before uploading the package to gcloud.

[Here is a link](https://github.com/woodpav/tal) to my solution.